# Is there something like a HttpCompletionOption in RestSharp?

Tags: c#, video-streaming, restsharp, dotnet-httpclient, blazor

I'd like to do something like this in Blazor:

```
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient
{
    Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(Timeout.Infinite) };
    var request = await httpClient.GetAsync("https://this.is.my.url", HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
    var stream = await request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
    var bufferedStream = new BufferedStream(stream);
}
```

but Blazor ignores the `HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead`.

For this reason, I've searched for an alternative to the `HttpClient` class.

RestSharp could be the solution to my problem, but I can't find an option to tell the RestClient that the operations should be considered completed as soon as a response is available and not after reading the entire response message including the content.

Is there something like the `HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead` in RestSharp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you work in client-side Blazor, then it is not possible achieve what you want, since HttpClient work over HTTP API `fetch` and you are subject to all browser restrictions as usually.

Other option is switch your project to server-side Blazor and let your code run on the server, when you will have standard .NET running your code.

Answer (score 0):

You could try `request.SetBrowserResponseStreamingEnabled(true)` (https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.webassembly.http.webassemblyhttprequestmessageextensions.setbrowserresponsestreamingenabled?view=aspnetcore-6.0)